# Magento 2 : How to create simple example of React JS Module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, react

How to create simple example of React JS Module?

Answer (score 1):

ReactJs has been seen at some places related to frontend but I haven't done it by myself yet.
Here is a link to a Magento module from Git which can assist you to make a demo for yourself.

https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2

Answer (score 1):

[Magento PWA GraphCommerce](https://www.graphcommerce.org/) features a react Magento 2 example project, components, and it's simple to set up.

https://github.com/graphcommerce-org/graphcommerce